# convert all rows into one row while spreading columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table.

```
+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+
| Level | Entry |  Code  | Name | Value  |
+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+
| L1    |   111 | Item_1 | pcs  |   1    |
| L2    |   222 | Item_2 | ctn  |   6    |
+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+
```

I want to query into this.

```
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| L1Entry | L1Code | L1Name | L1Value | L2Entry | L2Code | L2Name | L2Value |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
|     111 | Item_1 | pcs    |       1 |     222 | Item_2 | ctn    |       6 |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
```

It could be done by

```
;with L1 AS
(select Entry As L1Entry, Code As L1Code, Name As L1Name, Value As L1Value
from table
where Level = 'L1')
, L2 AS
(select Entry As L2Entry, Code As L2Code, Name As L2Name, Value As L2Value
from table
where Level = 'L2')
select * from L1
outer apply L2
```

Is there any better way than this in performance?

Comment: Are you sure it`s a good idea?if you have many Entry you`ll get a table a Km long

Comment: @Mihai I want to use it on UOM table. it has only 4 UOM level per one item. And I am seeing only one item at a time. So, it is no problem. I think there is a better way like windowing. I just don't know how.

Comment: Why don't you Use Pivot.

Comment: @KumarHarsh Pivot will not solve the problem, as it will change the rows and columns positions and will calculate the values based on the new decoration.

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating the problem. It is a simple join and I think the performace will be the same:

```
select * 
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.level = 'l1' and t2.level = 'l2'
```

Comment: Well done. Your code has a bit better performance than the provided CTE on my PC.